# Android server connection error from real device.

Tags: java, android, local, host

How to connect Android app to server on Local host:
1st. Using:- 192.168.0.1:8080 (Using my IP or dns getway)
. . . Or. . . .
2nd.Using:- Localhost:8080
. . . . Or. . . .
3rd. USING:- 10.0.0.2:8080

## Main point is:-

**MY app does connect on server using 1st option on EMULATOR**
*BUT when i try to run on Real device it throws connection timed out exception after 7 seconds
As I'm giving it setTimeOut(7000)*
Is there any solution?
I have read hundreds of post on the Internet about this problem but haven't found a perfect solution!!!

Comment: make sure your device and your PC connect in same wifi connection.

Comment: Yes Device is on the **same network**.

Comment: Can you post your logcat ??

Comment: There's no big issue in log cat just it's throwing an exception when i'm Running my App on real device that is **Socket Connection Timed Out Exception**  :( .....But i can't figure out why the heck it's throwing this exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using you a real device , the first option will work provided the device is on the same network as your computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a real device, please connect your device and computer same network.

Then, you determine your computer LAN IP (use `ipconfig` if Windows, `ifconfig` if using Linux). Example: `192.168.1.15`.

Connect to IP found.

IP `10.0.0.2` only work on emulator.

Comment: Hey, First of all i've used ipconfig from cmd and using **IPv4 Address** as URL.

Comment: Please tell me what ip you used to connect

Comment: this one **192.168.0.4**

Comment: And you still could not connect, please show me all result of `ipconfig` command. 
You sure mobile and pc connect same LAN network?

Comment: Literally i'm fed-up. I'm using a broadband connection and all device in our home is connected through a wifi of same broadband connection.Everything i'm doing in my server,APP and in my website(IN-DEVELOPMENT) is not connecting from Real device while the same link is working fine from Emulator of Android Studio.

Comment: Here is my ipconfig reult   ** Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : domain.name
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9958:df0e:8de9:1895%6
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.7
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::56b8:aff:fe9d:56af%6
                                       192.168.0.1

**

Comment: Please replace your url by `192.168.0.7`. I'm sorry if your device cannot to PC.